# Laravel view not displaying data

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to pass data to a laravel blade and get that displayed. Evidently I am missing something very basic. If I use laravel format `{{ $test_message }}`, it is not displaying the value. If I use `<?php echo  $test_message ; ?>`. It is working. Code from my controller -

```
$data = ['message' => 'This is a test!'];
return view('test')->with([ 'test_message' => $data['message'] ]);
```

View

```
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> <?php echo  $test_message ; ?> </p>
    <p> {{ $test_message }}  </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the output, I have "This is a test! " for the php echo portion and {{$test_message}} for the next line.

Comment: What is your view file named?

Comment: test.php. I tried making changes to it and made sure that is indeed getting picked up. By the way, I am using php artisan serve command to test locally. Would that have any impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that your view is missing the `blade` part of the extension and so Laravel is not running it through the blade compiler.

Rename it to `test.blade.php`.

Comment: Man...how can I give you a million upvotes? Spent a day on this, and started using plain php code.

Comment: No need - glad I could help! Sometimes it's the smallest things!

Answer (score 0):

try this

and your view name should be **test.blade.php**

```
return view('test',['test_message' => $data['message']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('test')->with('test_message', $data['message']);
```

or

```
return view('test',['test_message' => $data['message']]);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25454975)

Comment: @devpato There is no link in the answer

Comment: I'm sorry you are right I was reviewing answer and I have most clicked on the wrong option Stackoverflow gave me. I meant to flag the option that the answer doesn't give  any proper explanation, just the code